# Webpack: Change in one entry point file recompiling all?

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack config with multiple entry points so I can compile different  parts of a large website. There aren't any co-dependencies between the entry points (except they all share the same node_modules directory as they are in the same solution).

Should I expect a change in one of the files contained within an entry point to trigger a complete rebuild of everything? E.g. modifying a file within entry1 triggers entry 2/3/4/5's files to be recompiled.

In addition, a change to the .scss file within one of the entry point files also appears to trigger all javascript files to be recompiled (part of the site contains a React app, for example).

```
entry: {
    entry1: ['./assets/build/entry1.js'],
    entry2: ['./assets/build/entry2.js'],
    entry3: ['./assets/build/entry3.js'],
    entry4: ['./assets/build/entry4.js'],
    entry5: ['./assets/build/entry5.js']
},
```

**Edit:** To clarify, my question is: is there a way to configure webpack so it only rebuilds the bundle related to the entry point that's changed? E.g. if entry1 was a react app and entry 2 was a set of SASS or LESS files, why does a change to the react app source files trigger a rebuild of the style bundle?

Reason for my question is incremental rebuilds (in watch mode) that should take less than a second are taking 5+ seconds to recompile. If I comment out everything in the webpack config except the entry point I'm working on, I can get down to this short turnaround time.

I was hoping to avoid the need for multiple webpack configurations for each part of my app to be honest - maybe I'm doing something wrong or have missed a plugin!

Comment: Can you clarify, what is your question exactly?

Comment: No problem, I've added to the main question @YashuMittal

Comment: Did you try hot module reload?

Comment: webpack works how you think it does, it should only be rebuilding things it sees as dependencies. It sounds like you have some unexpected deps in there. I suggest trying to narrow it down. Try just entry1 with entry2 (etc etc) If you have a JS file that references one of the SASS files, they are dependent. webpack builds the dependency hierarchy by chasing references in files... make sure you don't have 2 entry points something unexpectedly pointing at the same file.

Comment: Actually, I tried to narrow down each entries for my own case, and it looks like that with Webpack4, if you have multiple entries and the default chunks splitting options, the rebuild is triggered even when nothing happens.

Comment: hi @DavidPeicho! You've mentioned "the default chunks splitting options". Are there some special options fixing the issue? Having same, totally isolated JS entry change makes independent SCSS entry recompile